# Gstreamer pipeline works with gst-launch but not in code. Reproducing a mjpeg stream from a IP camera

Tags: c, gstreamer, ip-camera, mjpeg

I want to reproduce a mjpeg stream from a intercom (but it's equivalent to a IP camera). Using gst-launch in the console works fine:

```
gst-launch-1.0 souphttpsrc location="http://192.168.1.191/api/camera/snapshot?width=640&height=480&fps=10" timeout=5 ! multipartdemux !  jpegdec ! videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

However, when I try to build an application to do this, it doesn't work.

My code:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>  

/* Structure to contain all our information, so we can pass it to callbacks */
typedef struct _CustomData {
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstElement *source;
  GstElement *v_demux;
  GstElement *v_decoder;
  GstElement *v_convert;
  GstElement *v_sink;
} CustomData;

/* Handler for the pad-added signal */
static void pad_added_handler (GstElement *src, GstPad *pad, CustomData *data);

/** Main function */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CustomData data;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;
  gboolean terminate = FALSE;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Create the elements
   *
   * souphttpsrc -> multipartdemux  (~>) jpegdec  -> videoconvert  -> ximagesink
   *
   * ~> Sometimes pad
   *
   * */
  data.source = gst_element_factory_make ("souphttpsrc", "video_source");
  data.v_demux = gst_element_factory_make ("multipartdemux", "video_demux");
  data.v_decoder = gst_element_factory_make ("jpegdec", "video_decoder");
  data.v_convert = gst_element_factory_make ("videoconvert", "video_convert");
  data.v_sink = gst_element_factory_make ("ximagesink", "video_sink");


  /* Create the empty pipeline */
  data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("new-pipeline");

  if (!data.pipeline || !data.source ||
      !data.v_demux || !data.v_decoder || !data.v_convert || !data.v_sink ) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  /* Configure elements */
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.source), "location", argv[1], NULL);
  g_object_set(G_OBJECT(data.source), "timeout", 5, NULL);

  /* Link all elements that can be automatically linked because they have "Always" pads */
  gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (data.pipeline), data.source,
      data.v_demux, data.v_decoder, data.v_convert, data.v_sink,
      NULL);
  if (gst_element_link_many (data.source, data.v_demux, NULL) != TRUE ||
      gst_element_link_many (data.v_decoder, data.v_convert, data.v_sink, NULL) != TRUE ) {
    g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
    return -1;
  }

  /* Connect to the pad-added signal */
  g_signal_connect (data.v_demux, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (pad_added_handler), &data);

  /* Start playing */
  ret = gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
    return -1;
  }

  /* Listen to the bus */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (data.pipeline);
  do {
    msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
        GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

    /* Parse message */
    if (msg != NULL) {
      GError *err;
      gchar *debug_info;

      switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
          gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
          g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
          g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
          g_clear_error (&err);
          g_free (debug_info);
          terminate = TRUE;
          break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
          g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
          terminate = TRUE;
          break;
        case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
          /* We are only interested in state-changed messages from the pipeline */
          if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (msg) == GST_OBJECT (data.pipeline)) {
            GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
            gst_message_parse_state_changed (msg, &old_state, &new_state, &pending_state);
            g_print ("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s:\n",
                gst_element_state_get_name (old_state), gst_element_state_get_name (new_state));
          }
          break;
        default:
          /* We should not reach here */
          g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
          break;
      }
      gst_message_unref (msg);
    }
  } while (!terminate);

  /* Free resources */
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
  return 0;
}

/* This function will be called by the pad-added signal */
static void pad_added_handler (GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, CustomData *data) {
  GstPad *sink_pad = NULL;
  GstPadLinkReturn ret;
  GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;
  GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;
  const gchar *new_pad_type = NULL;

  g_print ("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME (new_pad), GST_ELEMENT_NAME (src));

  /* Get information of the new pad's type */
  new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps (new_pad);
  new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure (new_pad_caps, 0);
  new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name (new_pad_struct);

  /* Get pad from the correspondent converter */
  if (g_str_has_prefix (new_pad_type, "video")) {
    sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->v_decoder, "sink");
  } else {
    g_print ("  It has type '%s' -> So exit\n", new_pad_type);
    return;
  }

  /* If our converter is already linked, we have nothing to do here */
  if (gst_pad_is_linked (sink_pad)) {
    g_print ("  We are already linked. Ignoring.\n");
    gst_object_unref (sink_pad);
    return;
  }

  ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, sink_pad);
  if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (ret)) {
    g_print ("  Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", new_pad_type);
  } else {
    g_print ("  Link succeeded (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type);
  }

  /* Unreference the new pad's caps, if we got them */
  if (new_pad_caps != NULL) {
    gst_caps_unref (new_pad_caps);
  }

  /* Unreference the sink pad */
  if (sink_pad != NULL) {
    gst_object_unref (sink_pad);
  }
}
```

The output when I run the program:

```
Pipeline state changed from NULL to READY:
Pipeline state changed from READY to PAUSED:
Error received from element video_demux: Could not demultiplex stream.
Debugging information: multipartdemux.c(475): multipart_parse_header (): /GstPipeline:new-pipeline/GstMultipartDemux:video_demux:
Boundary not found in the multipart header
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried too without using multipartdemux, but with similar result. It works using gst-launch but not in code.

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work, however you might find it easier to use gst_parse_launch() to create the pipeline, instead of doing it manually. And maybe it will make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but due to the nature of the whole application (the snipet I posted here it's just the gstreamer part) where I have a video/audio server and that I'm working with embedded systems (and I need to optimize the process) gst-parse-launch it's not an option.
Thank you anyway for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have found sometimes that adding queues helps, maybe one before the jpegdec?  Also maybe try a jpegparse before the jpegdec.